# How to convert dates to UTC then to Dates and compare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Is there a way to run this query but convert the dates to UTC first? Rails is converting the dates to the timezone in the configuration. But this is throwing off reports that I am trying to create.

```
leads.where('"leads"."scheduled_on"::date - "leads"."created_at"::date = 0')
```

Comment: Why would it throw off reports? You're testing whether the dates are equal. If they are equal, the time zone conversion will still make them equal. And since dates in PostgreSQL are stored in UTC internally, there is no other time zone involved.

Comment: I am trying to figure out why I am getting leads returned that are not equal then... Could it be because schedule_on are saved as Dates and created_at are saved as DateTimes?

When I remove the timezone in the configuration file then I get the correct result.

Comment: *"saved as DateTimes"*? You mean `timestamp`? Or `timestamptz`? Also please edit question and show example where it returns row where values are not equal. And why didn't you just use `a <> b` instead of `a - b = 0`?

Comment: Also don't forget to check what's happening at the tie that the leads are originally saved into the db... not just the time you are comparing them.